# Getting the totals of columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying an SQL query (in Oracle) to group a dataset by the first character of column x, and get the total count of rows and the count as a percentage as well. For this I used the code below.

```
SELECT
    V1,
    COUNT(*) as "Count",
    to_char(COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER(), 'fm990.00')|| '%' AS "Percentage"
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN substr(x, 0, 1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'C'       THEN
                    'A'
                WHEN substr(x, 0, 1) BETWEEN 'J' AND 'R'       THEN
                    'B'
                WHEN substr(x, 0, 1) BETWEEN 'S' AND 'Z'       THEN
                    'C'
                WHEN substr(x, 0, 1) BETWEEN '1' AND '5'       THEN
                    'D'
                WHEN substr(x, 0, 1) BETWEEN '6' AND '7'       THEN
                    'E'
                WHEN substr(x, 0, 1) BETWEEN '8' AND '9'       THEN
                    'F'
                ELSE
                    'Unknown'
            END AS V1
        FROM
            table1
    )
group by
    V1
    order by "Count", V1;
```

Output:

```
V1        Count       Percentage
A            1            0.47%
B            1            0.47%
C            54           25.59%
D            66           31.28%
E            89           42.18%
```

Now I also want to get the totals of the Count and Percentage columns as below.

```
V1        Count       Percentage
A            1            0.47%
B            1            0.47%
C            54           25.59%
D            66           31.28%
E            89           42.18%
Total        211          99.99%
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
SELECT
V1,
COUNT(*) as "Count",
to_char(COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER(), 'fm990.00')|| '%' AS "Percentage"
FROM
(SELECT CASE  WHEN substr(x, 0, 1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'C'       THEN 'A'
            WHEN substr(x, 0, 1) BETWEEN 'J' AND 'R'       THEN 'B'
            WHEN substr(x, 0, 1) BETWEEN 'S' AND 'Z'       THEN 'C'
            WHEN substr(x, 0, 1) BETWEEN '1' AND '5'       THEN 'D'
            WHEN substr(x, 0, 1) BETWEEN '6' AND '7'       THEN 'E'
            WHEN substr(x, 0, 1) BETWEEN '8' AND '9'       THEN 'F'
            ELSE 'Unknown'
        END AS V1
    FROM table1
) group by  V1 order by "Count", V1

union 

SELECT 'Total', sum(count), sum(val)|| '%' AS "Percentage"
(SELECT
V1,
COUNT(*) as "Count",
to_char(COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER(), 'fm990.00') as val;
FROM
(SELECT CASE  WHEN substr(x, 0, 1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'C'       THEN 'A'
            WHEN substr(x, 0, 1) BETWEEN 'J' AND 'R'       THEN 'B'
            WHEN substr(x, 0, 1) BETWEEN 'S' AND 'Z'       THEN 'C'
            WHEN substr(x, 0, 1) BETWEEN '1' AND '5'       THEN 'D'
            WHEN substr(x, 0, 1) BETWEEN '6' AND '7'       THEN 'E'
            WHEN substr(x, 0, 1) BETWEEN '8' AND '9'       THEN 'F'
            ELSE 'Unknown'
        END AS V1
    FROM table1
) group by  V1 order by "Count", V1) a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `union all` your query with the total amount

```
your query
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TOTAL', COUNT(*), '100%'
FROM table1
GROUP BY 1;
```

This adds another row with the total count (which is also always 100%).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest calculating the total in the subquery and then using `GROUPING SETS`:

```
SELECT V1, COUNT(*) as "Count",
       ROUND((COUNT(*) * 100.0 / MAX(total), 2) as p
FROM (SELECT (CASE WHEN substr(x, 0, 1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'C' THEN 'A'
                   WHEN substr(x, 0, 1) BETWEEN 'J' AND 'R' THEN 'B'
                   WHEN substr(x, 0, 1) BETWEEN 'S' AND 'Z' THEN 'C'
                   WHEN substr(x, 0, 1) BETWEEN '1' AND '5' THEN 'D'
                   WHEN substr(x, 0, 1) BETWEEN '6' AND '7' THEN 'E'
                   WHEN substr(x, 0, 1) BETWEEN '8' AND '9' THEN 'F'
                   ELSE  'Unknown'
               END) AS V1,
              COUNT(*) OVER () as total
      FROM table1
     ) t1
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (V1), () )
ORDER BY "Count", V1;
```

EDIT:

Based on your comment, you are stuck with a `union all` approach:

```
WITH t as (
      SELECT V1, COUNT(*) as "Count",
             TO_CHAR(COUNT(*) * 100.0 / MAX(total)|| '%' AS "Percentage"
      FROM (SELECT (CASE WHEN substr(x, 0, 1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'C' THEN 'A'
                         WHEN substr(x, 0, 1) BETWEEN 'J' AND 'R' THEN 'B'
                         WHEN substr(x, 0, 1) BETWEEN 'S' AND 'Z' THEN 'C'
                         WHEN substr(x, 0, 1) BETWEEN '1' AND '5' THEN 'D'
                         WHEN substr(x, 0, 1) BETWEEN '6' AND '7' THEN 'E'
                         WHEN substr(x, 0, 1) BETWEEN '8' AND '9' THEN 'F'
                         ELSE  'Unknown'
                     END) AS V1
            FROM table1
           ) t1
      GROUP BY V1
     )
SELECT v1, "Count", "Percentage"
FROM t
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Total', SUM("Count"),
       TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(REPLACE("Percentage", '%', '')), 'fm990.00')|| '%' 
FROM t
```

Comment: I tried this approach earlier but the concern I have is my percentage column should add up to 99.99% due to rounding off errors in the values, but this returns 100%

Comment: @DAS . . . Interesting.  Usually people want the total to still represent reality, not rounding errors.  But I can see the use for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROLLUP` here as follows:

```
SELECT COALESCE(V1, 'Total'), CNT, PRCNT FROM
(SELECT V1, SUM(CNT) AS CNT, SUM(PRCNT) AS PRCNT
FROM (<your_existing_query>)
GROUP BY ROLLUP(V1))
```